# external javascript file not working in .net core MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have the following code which works if i insert it directly into my html page, however when i try to make an external reference it does not work

please advsie
Ehi

When called externally, I use

```
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/CarParts2018.js"></script>
```

and when I insert into my html page, the code is

```
    <script>
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";


    }
</script>
<script>
    // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

and corresponding div is

```
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">Popular Searches</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Search ALPHABETICALLY</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Search by name</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: With Chrome Developper Tools (F12 on current page) have you an error 404 ? or something in the console panel ?

Comment: First, don't put your scripts in lib, especially under a library like bootstrap. The whole point is that those folders should be able to be updated in place potentially wiping and replacing with a new checkout of the library. Your custom scripts should go in `wwwroot/js`.

Comment: <script src="~/CarParts2018.js"></script>      I have updated it, but it still does not work :'(

Comment: Answer me pls. And edit your question with your application file tree

Comment: @GGO If i right click and choose view source, I can see the external jscript file, however if i press f12 in chrome, it does not appear

Comment: what is an application file tree ?

Comment: in the f12 window, I get the error - uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token and my jscript file is highlighted in red under console

Comment: If you click on the error, wuat line is red ?

Comment: I found the problem, it was the script tags, and the chrome developer tools highlighted it saying Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  so removing it solved the problem

Comment: thank you GGO and Chris Pratt

Comment: @Ehi Accept my answer to close the topic so. Checking the green tick

Comment: how  do i mark the answer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cf comments : In a javascript file you can't use `<script>` html tag. Javascript file can only contains javascript commands.

See javascript basic documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics)